# Polynomial vector as ordered set notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if it's correct to write a polynomial in linear algebra with ordered set notation.

I have seen some matrix written as:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \end{bmatrix} = (a, b, c ,d) $$

So I thought:

$$ a x^{2}+ bx + c = (a, b, c) $$

Can I do it?

Comment: Both give you all the information you need about a general quadratic polynomial, but the latter will be meaningless without context.

Comment: You're essentially observing that if you have a field $K$ and consider the space $K[x]_{\leq n}$ of polynomials with degree at most $n$, then there is a natural linear one-to-one correspondence $K[x]_{\leq n} \to K^{n+1}$ given by $\sum_{0 \leq i \leq n} a_ix^i \mapsto (a_i)_{0 \leq i \leq n}$.

Comment: You can use whatever notation is meaningful to yourself and the people reading it.

Comment: The only purely *improper* notation is one that is self-inconsistent. Yet a notation that’s not congruent to established notation will need much more explanation and justification.

Comment: Better it would be to write down as a scalar product $=(a,b,c)(x^2,x,1)^T $

Comment: @Widawensen may I ask what is the T in the second parentheses?

Comment: @CarlosEduardo Transposition. If $(a,b,c)$ is treated as a row vector then scalar product can be written down this way where $(x^2, x,1)^T$ is now column vector.

Comment: @Widawensen oh, got it now. I was able to do step by step. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as $(a,b,c)$ if you give context. Your notation is not entirely unestablished but is reversed relative to what I'm used to seeing: there is the polynomial vector space $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ where the vector $(a,b,c)$ represents $a+bx+cx^2$ like you desire, where $x$ is a real number. Vectors here will follow the same rules as those in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$. There is a similar vector space for all natural numbers $n$ over a field $F$, written as $P_n(F)$.